# Does Silverlight Support Bitmap datatype

Tags: silverlight-4.0, types

Hello Guys I am working on silverlight application and I want to make some color contrast and brightness so I am going to use with Bitmap datatype,but i am not able to do this.

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WriteableBitmap to work with bitmaps programmatically. Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality that allows you to change the contract/brightness of an image.